# Call to undefined relationship [categories] on model [App\Product]

Tags: laravel-7

I have three tables (products, categories, sizes) and models (Product, Category, Size) respectively.

In my product table I saved `category_id` and `size_id` respectively.

For list view I want to fetch `category_name` from category table and `size_name` using size table respectively.

I am using relation for that purpose. Below is model structure of relationship.

**Product**:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
    public function size()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Size::class);
    }
}
```

**Category**:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

**Size**:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Size extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Below is my controller where I want fetch data with category name and size name. Then want to send data to list view with category name and size name to display:

```php
public function productList()
{
    // $product = Product::get();
    $data = Product::with('categories','sizes')->get();
    echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($product->category->name);
    // return view('admin.productlist',['productdata' => $data]);
}
```

Below is my migration file of product:

```php
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('product_name');
    $table->string('product_category')->nullable();
    $table->string('product_price');
    $table->string('product_size')->nullable();
    $table->string('product_stock')->nullable();
    $table->string('product_description')->nullable();
    $table->string('created_user_id')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Size migration:

```php
Schema::create('sizes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('product_size');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Category Migration :

```php
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong then please help me in that.

My list blade file is below:

```php
@foreach ($productdata as $product)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$product->product_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->product_category}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->product_size}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->product_price}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: 1) When you use `with()`, you reference your relationships, which are the methods you define in your models.  `with('categories')` means *load the `categories` relationship*. But you have no `categories()` relationship/method in your Product model, only `category`.  Try `with('category')`.  Same problem for `sizes`. 2) I am not sure but I think you may have your relationships wrong. A product probably belongs to many categories, right?  Eg a car could be "electric", "4wd", "family".  And a category can be assigned to many products.  That sounds like a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I am not getting your first point. About 2nd point relationship. Relationship like One category have multiple product nd that product belogs to that category and same for size.

Comment: @Don't Panic i changed into the model function as categories but i am getting null value in that variable----------{"id":1,"product_name":"Mi Mobile","product_category":"2","product_price":"15000","product_size":"3","product_stock":"300","product_description":"One of the Best mobile in World","created_user_id":"1","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"categories":null,"sizes":null}